# SSAS: How to use .net DLL and stored procedures in ssas using Assemblies

Tags: sql-server, ssas, msbi

How to  call the .Net DLL and stored procedures in ssas assemblies and how to get the result using that stored procedure or Dll's

1) i created simple stored procedure name like division it returns division value of two numbers

2) After that i created on DLL Using .net using Stored Procedure

3) After creating DLL ,this DLL i used in ssas Assemblies

4) finally I want use this DLL in my calculations

```
create member CURRENTCUBE.[measures].[assemblies]
as(select( ssas_practice_division_method.maths.division(1,2)) ),
format_string='00.00', 
visible=1;
```

But i getting  invalid method name

Answer (score 0):

You mention that after creating the dll, you have used it in SSAS Assemblies. There are 2 steps to this:
1) Add the assembly to the SSAS project in BIDS/SSDT.
2) Add the assembly to the SSAS server, either on the server itself or at database the level.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175398.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- First, be sure to add the assembly reference either at database or server level. You can do this by right clicking Assemblies from either SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) OR SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

  [image: Add assembly reference to your project]
- In Properties, to first test out using an MDX query, give it either 'Unrestricted' or 'External Access' Permission Set.

  [image: Set Properties of an Assembly]
- Now, go to SSMS and create a new MDX query on your SSAS database which looks like this:

  [image: Write an MDX Query to test out stored procedure]
- I get the above result when I have the following method in MyClass inside MyAssembly.

  `namespace MyAssembly
  {
      public class MyClass
      {
          public static double MyFunction(int a, int b)
          {
              return a / b;
          }
      }
  }`

Comment: i followed your instructions but i'm getting this error "[MyAssembly].[MyFunction]' function does not exist."

Comment: Even with 'public static' Access Modifiers for function? And 'Unrestricted Access' Permission Set for the assembly? I might need a few more details. How and at which level are you deploying the assembly? Database or server? Are you positive that the assembly gets deployed correctly?

Comment: function modifier is public and access unrestricted and i am deployed at server level and assembly deployed successfully it showing sql also

Comment: I don't understand what's the issue here. I checked by executing the same query after deploying the assembly at either levels and it did execute. I suspect the assembly might be blocked, try unblocking it as [given here.](http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20Instructions&referringTitle=Home)